# Циклы и массивы

Tags: c++

Как написать программу ? который при входе получит unsigned  и получит все простые числа перед этим unsigned числом. ‘Unsigned A,B’ while A/B=1’ как то так?

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык или задайте его на enSO. Энивей, надо привести свои попытки

Comment: @dIm0n этот вопрос надо на фрилансе задать, не?

Comment: @Данил ну если ТС не покажет "стремления разобраться", то да

Comment: Перевели -- отлично, теперь надо уточнить, в чём проблема. Например, привести код, который вы написали, чтобы решить проблему, и возникшие ошибки/неправильный вывод

Comment: Ну как использовать while and for я уже поняла но не получается вывести все простые числа. Простое число например 2,3,5... 2/2=1 да? Нужно решить задание с помощью этого? Например А/B==1 или как?

Answer (score 0):

У вас обычная задача на поиск простых чисел, вот один из вариантов решения:

```
int main () 
{
   cout << "Введите число: ";
   unsigned int num = 0;
   cin >> num;
   for (int i=2; i<num; i++) 
        for (int j=2; j*j<=i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0) 
                break;
            else if (j+1 > sqrt(i)) {
                cout << i << " ";

            }

        }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Классный else на фоне условия в for ;)

Comment: И сделайте код компилируемым без дополнительных действий

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое !